# How to assign user ID automatically in PHP upon user register?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I am looking at creating user ID automatically upon user registration. I've coded the files using Laravel and the database uses MySQL. The format should be S0001, S0002, S0003, so on and so forth.

What kind of datatype I should change it to in MySQL? Currently it is set at BIGINT.

If yes, how do I proceed with the code then?

This code below is from viewuser.blade.php:

```
{{View:: make('title')}}
{{View:: make('menu')}}

<div class="table-responsive">
    <table class="table table-striped table-sm">
        <!-- <caption>List of Users</caption> -->
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th scope="col">#</th>
                    <th scope="col">User ID</th>
                    <th scope="col">Full Name</th>
                    <th scope="col">Email Address</th>
                    <th scope="col">Password</th>
                    <th scope="col">Action</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>

            <tbody>
            @foreach($users as $user)
                <tr>
                    <td>{{ $loop->iteration}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $loop->iteration}}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->name }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->email }}</td>
                    <td>{{ $user->password }}</td>
                    <td>{{ date('D, d F Y', strtotime($user->created_at)) }}</td>
                    <td>
                        <a href="/editmyuser?rid={{ $user->id }}">Edit</a>
                        <a href="/editmyuser?rid={{ $user->id }}">Delete</a>
                    </td>
                </tr>
                @endforeach
            </tbody>
    </table>
</div>

<div class="pagination">
    {{ $users->links() }}
</div>
```

And this is the Register Page code, in case it's useful:

```
{{View:: make('title')}}

<div>
    <form action="register" method="post">
    @csrf

        <div>
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Full Name</label>
            <input type="text" name="fullname" id="exampleInputName1">
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Email Address</label>
            <input type="email" name="email" id="exampleInputEmail1" aria-describedby="emailHelp">

            <div id="emailHelp">We'll never share your email with anyone else
            </div>
        </div>

        <div>
            <label for="exampleInputPassword1">Password</label>
            <input type="password" name="password" id="exampleInputPassword1">
        </div>

        <button type="submit">Register</button>
        <button type="button" onclick="javascript:history.back()">Cancel</button>

    </form>
</div>

{{View:: make('footer')}}
```

Comment: Is there a reason why the id's need that format? MySQL won't be able to automatically increase the id's if they are in that format (since `S0001` is a string, not an int, bigint or any kind of numeric value). You could just use int/bigint as primary auoti increment key as usual in your db, but add the `S000` part in your application layer. Just prefix it with `S` and use [str_pad()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) to add the zeros. If you then need to search for an id, just remove the `S` and cast the value as an int before using it in your query.

Comment: Also remember that `S0001` limits the amount of records to `9999`, unless the string can suddenly be longer?

Answer (score 1):

Why not just use the existing `id` column on the `Users` table, then define a `prefix` column in your `Users` table that you can prepend to the `id` whenever you want to display it.

**Users table migration**

```
$table->string('prefix')->default('S');
```

**Users model**

Then you can do something like define an [`accessor`](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-mutators#defining-an-accessor) on your model to return the combined value of the `id` and `prefix` columns:

```
class User extends Model
{
    protected function matriculationNumber()
    {
        return $this->prefix . str_pad($this->id, 3, '0', STR_PAD_LEFT);
    }
}
```